# Vue.js - Set dynamic checkbox value true/false

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have table which has some list of products, now for every product there is an upload file and a completed checkbox,

```
<vs-table :data="fileUpload">
   <template slot="header">
      <h3>
         Upload Files
      </h3>
   </template>
   <template slot="thead">
      <vs-th>
         Data
      </vs-th>
      <vs-th>
         Upload Files
      </vs-th>
      <vs-th>
         Uploaded
      </vs-th>
   </template>
   <template slot-scope="{ data }">
      <vs-tr :key="indextr" v-for="(tr, indextr) in data">
         <!--<vs-tr>-->
         <vs-td>
            {{tr}}
         </vs-td>
         <vs-td>
            <div class="centerx">
               <input type="file" v-on:change="handleFileUpload($event,indextr)" />
            </div>
         </vs-td>
         <vs-td>
            <vs-checkbox v-model="completedCheckboxes" :vs-value="indextr"></vs-checkbox>
         </vs-td>
      </vs-tr>
   </template>
</vs-table>
```

now on the change event of **handleFileUpload** I want to set the checkbox next to it as true.

```
handleFileUpload: async function(event,checkboxIndex) {
//set checkbox for that row here
}

 data() {
    return {
    completedCheckboxes:[],
 }
}
```

now i do get the checboxes value in **completedCheckboxes** array If i select them manually, but cant seem to work through code, I went over many solutions but nothing worked for me, any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the check box is the index try to push that uploaded file index to the `completedCheckboxes` array :

```
handleFileUpload: async function(event,checkboxIndex) {
    this.completedCheckboxes.push(checkboxIndex)
}
```

Comment: That did the trick, thanks buddy keep up the good work!

Comment: @uneebmeer does it need to be `async`?

Comment: in my case the file upload was needed to be done async thats why i added that, that was not related to the actual problem you can leave that out.